# Showing logo image for mobile devices for blogger

Tags: css, coding-style, styles, blogs, blogger

I am working on blog at blogger and it has got a responsive template. When I see logo on my blog on the computer it looks fine but when I go to iPhone it is kind of blurred and I don't know what is the reason for that.
I tried to edit logo and change it for different one but the result is the same...

Link to my blog is: www.5minLunchBox.blogspot.com

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your natural width is 220px width. But your mobile viewport width exceeds that amount to 320px to 480px depending on the mobile device. Not to mention, you are using a .jpg image which is highly pixelated.

**SOLUTIONS**

1. Familiarize yourself with .svg technology. Using an SVG will allow you to manipulate the image at all widths and make use of your `max-width:100%;`.
2. Use a larger image (no smaller than 480px) this way, you can still resize down without losing resolution, and not have a need to re-size up, which is your problem here. You are expanding .jpg pixels

Once you have added a larger logo, hopefully a .png at least, but preferably an .svg, do the following:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  .widget iframe, .widget img {
      width:100%;
      max-width: 320px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the real logo jpg dimensions are: `200x90 pixels`. On the desktop version set the width to `200px` but the smartphone version set the width to `100%`. For this, on an `iPhone 6`, the logo width become `375px` and the image appears blurred and pixelated (on `iPad` become `768px`). 
You could augment the real size of the jpg logo, but the file size could be too big. If you can change the image format you could convert the logo to `svg`.